# Are GAE instances limited to 10 concurrent request?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, go

I've heard from several sources that Google App Engine Instances have a hard limit of 10 concurrent request. I was wondering if someone could clarify what exactly this means.

Does the scheduler block any requests over the 10, or is this enforced through a limit on concurrent threads?

Specifically, does this limit affect Go instances the same way that it does Python and Java?

> EDIT: here's the feature request which will allow App Engine Instance to
>   handle more then 10 concurrent request / threads. [Allow configurable limit of
>   concurrent requests per
>   instance](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7927).
>   Please star it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed as of Nov 18th 2013.

The maximum number of requests any GAE instance can process is now configured via the `max_concurrent_requests` setting eg:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1
automatic_scaling:
  max_concurrent_requests: 80

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: _go_app
```

The default is 8 and the maximum is 80.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling for more info.

Answer (score 8):

As of July 12, 2012, it's the latter. The 10 concurrent limit is enforced through a limit on concurrent threads on every runtime. Most of such cases, our scheduler will try to spin up a new instance.

Please also see the e-mail from jonmac on this thread:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/y-LnZ2WYJ5Q/j_w13F4oSSkJ

Comment: Thank you Takashi. And just to clarify the Go runtime is multithreaded? Also, do you know of a feature request for an increase in thread limit. I couldn't locate one through the search.

Comment: The Go runtime is single-threaded on GAE (GOMAXPROCS=1). The  reason for that is that it is possible to do arbitrary pointer arithmetic by creating race conditions with multiple threads. But don't worry, you can still write concurrent programs in Go by spawning several thousand goroutines.

Comment: @tux21b Thank you. So does that mean that the 10 concurrent thread limitation will not not have an adverse affect on Go Apps? I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. I thought that Go multiplexed goroutines over OS threads, when request where blocked by I/O. If that's the case and the Go runtime is single threaded then would any I/O call block the entire instance?

Comment: @tux21b I created a separate question of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446602/how-does-go-handle-concurrent-request-on-google-app-engine