# How does Go handle concurrent request on Google App Engine

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, go

I'm a little confused on how Go handles concurrent requests on Google App Engine. So I'm hoping someone can provide some clarity.

Here are the facts that I have gathered:

1. Go is single threaded on App Engine. - [this is because it is possible to do arbitrary pointer arithmetic by creating race conditions with multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443482/236564)
2. [Goroutines are multiplexed onto multiple OS threads so if one should block, such as while waiting for I/O, others continue to run.](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines)
3. [[App Engine has a] 10 concurrent limit [which] is enforced through a limit on concurrent threads on every runtime. Most of such cases, our scheduler will try to spin up a new instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443482/236564)

If Go is single threaded on App Engine then point 3 is moot. This leaves 1 and 2. If Go on App Engine is single threaded and threads are required to continue execution while blocking for I/O, then it seems that an App Engine Go instance will block all goroutines while waiting on I/O.

Is this correct? If not how does Go's concurrency really work on App Engine?

To help quantify things. If I were to hold a connection open for 30 seconds. How may concurrent connections could a single AE Go instance maintain?

Thank you.

> EDIT: here's the feature request which will allow Go Instance to
>   handle more then 10 concurrent request [Allow configurable limit of
>   concurrent requests per
>   instance](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7927).
>   Please star it.

Comment: Setting GOMAXPROCS=1 (that is what GAE does) just means that  there will be always exactly one active thread that executes goroutines. You might still have a couple of blocked threads (they don't count). Also note, that the Go library uses epoll in the background, so that I/O is unlikely to block a whole thread (but there are several other ways to block a thread in Go). I don't know anything about the general 10 thread limit on GAE though.

Comment: The concurrent request limit is now configurable (up to a max of 80), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37364981/943833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for an answer and happened upon this question/answers, but also ended up finding more official documentation on the matter.  According to a [post by Andrew Gerrand and Johan Euphrosine](https://blog.golang.org/appengine-dec2013#TOC_4.) this can be explicitly configured.

From that post:

> This configures each instance of the app to serve up to 100 requests concurrently (up from the default of 10). You can configure Go instances to serve up to a maximum of 500 concurrent requests.

Answer (score 22):

A Go App Engine instance allows 10 concurrent requests, but only runs one CPU thread. In effect, multiple requests can be processed concurrently, but only one will be able to do CPU work at a time. If one request is, say, waiting for a datastore API call to return, another request is free to be processed by the same instance.

Your statement "If Go is single threaded on App Engine then point 3 is moot." is incorrect. There is still a limit of 10 concurrent in-flight requests to a single Go App Engine instance. The documentation is a bit loose with words when it talks about "threads".

Comment: **This answer needs much greater propagation.** I have understood that the Go runtime queues requests, so that an incoming request would have to wait until the current request was fully processed. It was obvious that a single request could spawn many go routines and operate concurrently, but not that many go routines could.

Comment: The docs do say "multiple requests may be handled concurrently by a given instance", but I never got that far through the paragraph until I reread it just now, having stopped at the single-threaded limitation.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm still a little unclear on the request throttling. I took [Takashi's response here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11443482/236564) to mean that all instance where limited by 10 concurrent threads rather then requests. It seems that this may have changed recently. Is that not true for Go?  If it is indeed threads, what would be a practical limit for the number of concurrent requests a F1 Go instance could handle?

Comment: I can't speak for Python and Java, but Go is not running multi-threaded on App Engine. There's exactly one thread for each Go app instance, but up to 10 concurrent requests can be handled by it.

As to what an F1 instance can handle, it depends very much on the workload. If all the requests are doing is fetching some stuff from datastore, munging it a bit and spitting it back out, there's no reason it couldn't handle a lot more than 10 concurrent requests.

Comment: @dsymonds Regarding your last sentence (handling much more than 10 concurrent requests with datastore-bound workloads) -- this is exactly what I was thinking... So what is the rationale for limiting each instance to only 10 requests? I this limit expected to be lifted? I'm just getting started on a project that I expect this to make a big difference for.

Answer (score 4):

I must admit I have no inside knowledge of AppEngine. This is all speculation and guessing, but I think it is somewhat reasonable.

Your app will never reach the ten thread limit. This is because there are very few reasons for threads to be created. First, the maximum number of goroutines running at once is set to one to [enforce memory safety](http://research.swtch.com/gorace). Second, unlike a normal go program, app engine does not actually need to make syscalls. The only time it does is for networking. All IO in appengine can be muxed into one epoll thread. This means all you need is two threads at any given time. You can then add a third or forth thread in case every once in a while you need to run other syscalls such as allocating memory and accepting/closing connections. These are fast syscalls that block for a very small amount of time. Even with these other syscalls, you are still very far from the ten thread limit.

Concurrency is not affected because in the end, everything you do in appengine boils down to waiting for something over the network to return. You do not need multiple threads to be doing many things at once.

Comment: @KyleFinley, if you're not too familiar with that "epoll stuff", I highly advice at least skimming through the classic ["The C10K problem"](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) work.

Comment: @kostix Interesting article. Thank you.