# How many CPU cores used for Google App Engine instance classes

Tags: google-app-engine, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

Is there any technical documentation and details on the numbers of CPU cores used for the different Google App Engine instance Classes (B1-B8)?

If some instance classes use several CPU cores, it could be taken into consideration to get more real concurrency (as in concurrent multi processing, **not** as in threading because of GIL).

Comment: Reposted at Server Fault as instructed: http://serverfault.com/questions/581753/how-many-cpu-cores-used-for-google-app-engine-instance-classes

Answer (score 1):

Each backend or frontend instance only has a single CPU (core). The difference between the classes is the amount of RAM that can be utilized and the GHz of the CPU (i.e. how fast computations are done, although idle times for datastore and other RPCs can be considerable).

Comparison of instance classes in official docs:

- [Backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/backends?hl=en#Python_Instance_classes)
- [Frontend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Frontend_Instance_Class)

You have many ways to improve performance of your app, for example by using async calls to datastore, tasklets etc. Utilizing multiple instances is just one option (eventually more expensive) and there are also many different roads you can take, e.g. task-queues for deferred jobs, map & reduce. But for more helpful answers you would need to submit more specific details :-)

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525717/when-does-the-app-engine-scheduler-use-a-new-thread-vs-a-new-instance , proppy saied class 8 is 2 cores !