# Does google cloud app engine support tomcats default 200 threads?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was wondering how many threads can app engine support since I need it to calculate how many WebSocket connections I can support per instance.

Somewhere I read there are no threads, somewhere that you can use but no max number listed.

So can a single app engine instance support for example tomcats default 200 threads?

And if not what GCP service do you recommend for hosting such an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a connection with `websocket` you can have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/using-websockets-and-session-affinity?tab=python).
And about the number of thread limits, you can specify by defining `max_concurrent_requests` as discussed in similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37364981/18265570). It is also defined in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling:%7E:text=a%20new%20instance.-,max_concurrent_requests,-Optional.%20The%20number), that the maximum limit of `max_concurrent_requests` is 1000.

If you are willing to check on other services provided by GCP, you can choose `Cloud run` or Google Kubernetes engine for containerized applications as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/introducing-google-clouds-tomcat-migration-tooling) and also you can consider an option of [installing tomcat on virtual machine](https://bytesofgigabytes.com/googlecloud/installing-apache-tomcat-on-google-cloud/).